# Finding the MLE's when $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

We have a random sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution, $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I have to find the MLE of the following:

1. $P[X > c]$  for arbitrary $c$
2. The $95^\text{th}$ percentile of $X$

Could someone give me tips how to handle these kind of questions? I have solved MLE questions before, so I understand the idea behind it, however I couldn't answer these two unfortunately.

So far, I have standardized the $P[X>c]$ and I know have $P[X>c] = 1 - F_X[\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma}]$. I guess I can now conclude something, but I do not know what.

Comment: Your notation is incorrect in one particular: You need $F_X\left(\frac{c-\mu}\sigma\right),$ with a _capital_ subscript $X.$ Just remember the difference in meaning between (capital) $X$ and (lower-case) $x$ in such expressions as $\Pr(X\le x).$ The random variable is (capital) $X,$ whereas $x$ could be any particular fixed number. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I have changed it!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459415/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know that the MLE for the population mean is the sample mean $\overline x = (x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$ and the MLE for the population variance is the (biased) sample variance $s^2 = \big( (x_1-\overline x)^2 +\cdots + (x_n-\overline x)^2\big)/n$ then the rest is a matter of applying the theorem on **equivariance** of MLEs.

(You often see this incorrectly called "invariance" rather than "equivariance.")

The value of $c$ for which $\Pr(X>c)=0.95$ is $\mu + \sigma\Phi^{-1}(0.95),$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal c.d.f., so then **equivariance** tells you that $\widehat{c\,}_\text{m.l.e.} =\overline x + s\Phi^{-1}(0.95).$

Comment: I thought $s^2$ was divided by $n-1$; that may be me though. Regardless, I understand what to do now. Many thanks! @ Michael Hardy

Comment: @Murat Indeed, the MLE for $\sigma$ is not $s$ but $\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}} s$; Bessel's correction leads to an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$, but it is not the MLE.  This is explained in the answer (note the definition in the first paragraph, which deviates slightly from the conventional notation).

Comment: @heropup : Actually, both notations occur in the literature.

Comment: @Murat : $\big( (x_1-\overline x)^2 +\cdots + (x_n-\overline x)^2\big)/(n-1)$ is the best unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ and is often denoted by $s^2.$ And $\big( (x_1-\overline x)^2 +\cdots + (x_n-\overline x)^2\big)/n$ is the maximum-likelihood estimator of $\sigma^2,$ and is also sometimes denoted by $s^2.$ The notation varies somewhat with the context. $\qquad$

Comment: @heropup and Michael Hardy Thanks guys!